# Create a d3.js histogram based on already given frequencies

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have implemented the d3.js histogram, similar to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450). This works nicely, but due to the number of values in some use cases I would like to preprocess the data and pass already the necessary frequencies to d3.layout.histogram().

Instead of values `[13, 5, 88, 4]` I would have the following:

```
{ "0-5"   : 2,
  "5-10"  : 0,
  "10-15" : 1,
   ...
}
```

I guess this would save me the call to

```
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(20))
    (values);
```

but I am not sure how to integrate this properly. I would still need the d3.layout function to calculate the the width of the bins. The number of bins would be given through the number of properties in the given frequencies. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to pass the bins dynamically; but still allow the frequency calculations to be done by  `layout.histogram`

You could pass in an array to the `histogram.bins` method. Like so:

```
// Generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
var values= [13,5,88,4];
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(d3.range(0,100,6))
    (values);
```

You could even parameterize the call to `d3.range()` by finding the `min` and `max` of the `values` array. This would save you the time to create the associative array to find the frequencies

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I guess I have expressed myself ambiguously. What I really wanted is to calculate the frequencies myself (on the server side) and pass it to d3.layout. I have updated title and question a bit.

Comment: The  `histogram` layout may not help you here as it is [used](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Histogram-Layout#wiki-_histogram) for calculating the frequencies for the passed in data, which you already have. To calculate the widths for the bins as you specified, you could create a new `d3.scale` and use the `ticks` function.